# What is the best tool to see a website peak?

Tags: google-analytics, web, traffic

I want to know what time my website has been more visitors. How can I check this peak? Can I do with google analytics?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this with Google Analytics. Please note that there are steps that Google takes to prevent you from getting analytics at a level detailed enough to violate the privacy of a user, so you may not exactly get the answer you want if you have too long of a history, or too few users visiting over the period you are analyzing.

The other thing you need to be careful of is that most data is geared toward *sessions* whereas your question is asking about *visitors*.

The best way to measure this sort of data is if you have unique advertising identifiers, cookies, or a login page that is being captured in a way that allows you to track a unique visitor as it navigates through your site, and treat that separately from a user who double clicked on a particular page. If you have a database, or log files, or an event strip, or even are able to capture ip addresses somewhere of where the visits are coming, along with timestamps, this can help you get the answer you're looking for better than can be achieved directly from Google Analytics.

Another caveat with GA is that the data may continue to trickle in over 24 hour period or longer, so if the spike just happened, you'll want to wait a while before making a final analysis.

With Google Analytics, if you are trying to investigate a single peak in your data on a single day, and that day occurred at least 24 hours ago, then here's an example of one way to get time-segmented traffic data for a website:

- Log on to Google Analytics
- On the left hand side click to expand the "Audience" tab and click on "Overview"
- select the date range in the top right for instance April 1 - April 1 2016
- slightly below that select "Hourly" instead of day (top right of the chart)
- In the top left, click on Users instead of Sessions.
- You should now see an hourly view of the traffic over the period of April 1.
- I've attached a screenshot of this final page, taken from an old Google Analytics account that is tracking a defunct website (which is why there are so few data points)

[image: An example of the final page result on Google Analytics that a user should see after following the instructions above.]